# Python and API -> Cache file issue

Tags: python, api-design

Completely new to Python (Just learned from Code Academy; no real experience)!

I have this issue:

I would like to update python code/API in Crop model ([Link to github code](https://github.com/ajwdewit/pcse/blob/master/pcse/db/nasapower.py)), which harvest meteorological data from NASA POWER database ([Link to Nasa POWER API](https://power.larc.nasa.gov/docs/v1/)), becauase of new values and parameters.

Original API was:

```
server = "asdc-arcgis.larc.nasa.gov"        
t_url = ("https://{server}/cgi-bin/cgiwrap/solar/agro.cgi?" +
              "email=agroclim%40larc.nasa.gov&step=1&lat={lat}&lon={lon}" +
              "&ms=1&ds=1&ys=1984&me={month}&de={day}&ye={year}&p=toa_dwn&" +
              "p=swv_dwn&p=lwv_dwn&p=T2M&p=T2MN&p=T2MX&p=RH2M&" +
              "p=DFP2M&p=RAIN&p=WS10M&submit=Submit")
```

My intention/attempt:

```
server = "https://power.larc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/v1/DataAccess.py?"
t_url = (" https://power.larc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/v1/DataAccess.py?" +
             " request=execute&identifier=" +
             "&parameters=ALLSKY_TOA_SW_DWN,ALLSKY_SFC_SW_DWN,ALLSKY_SFC_LW_DWN,T2M,T2M_MIN,T2M_MAX,RH2M,T2MDEW,PRECTOT,WS10M" +
             "&startDate=19900101" +
             "&endDate=20160101&userCommunity=AG" +
             "&tempAverage=DAILY&outputList=JSON,ASCII,CSV&lat={lat}&lon={lon}&user=anonymous")
```

The error in command prompt after trying to connect to NASA POWER with specific coordinates:

```
 File "C:\Users...\pcse\db\nasapower.py", line 87, in __init__
cache_file = self._find_cache_file(self.latitude, self.longitude)
 File "C:\Users...\pcse\db\nasapower.py", line 232, in _find_cache_file
cache_filename = self._get_cache_filename(latitude, longitude)
 File "C:\Users...\pcse\db\nasapower.py", line 247, in _get_cache_filename
int(latitude*10), int(longitude*10))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

**I am not sure what is an issue**. Latitude and longitude seems fine to me. I was thinking about date (day, month, year) API, but there is no new documentation for a date format according to an actual day ((Star year = 1984; end year = date.today()). Some hint please?

PS:I've also changed all values in python code to new value names (e.g. RAIN -> PRECTOT).

Thank you!

Comment: Out of curiousity, what happens if you put in values for the {lat} and {lon} values?

Comment: Well actualy nothing because command for taking data from database is like this: 
pcse.db.NASAPowerWeatherDataProvider(latitude, longitude, force_update=False, ETmodel='PM'). So I think that you always need to put latitude and longitude values through command prompt. I've tried lat=50 and lon=50 and nothing happened...